# Adding WebGrid to a MembershipUserCollection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper, webgrid

Here's the snippet of my view that is giving me error

```
@model MembershipUserCollection
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@{var usersGrid = new WebGrid(source: Model, rowsPerPage: 40);}
```

apparently the WebGrid constructor does not accept a MembershipUserCollection as a parameter.
How can I get around this?

please help.
I need to add pagination to the list of Users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
@{var usersGrid = new WebGrid(source: Model.Cast<MembershipUser>(), rowsPerPage: 40);}
```

`MembershipUserCollection` implements the **non**-generic interface `IEnumerable`, whereas the WebGrid constructor parameter `source` is a generic `IEnumerable<T>`.  To convert from `IEnumerable` to `IEnumerable<T>`, use the `Cast` extension method on `IEnumerable`.